# Users relatedTo multiple categories

Tags: users, categories, relations

Trying to get users in a members group related to multiple categories.

```
{% set services = craft.categories.group('services').slug('service-1, service-2') %}
{% set locations = craft.categories.group('locations').slug('location-1') %}

{% set members = craft.users.group("members").relatedTo("and", { targetElement: services }, { targetElement: locations } ) %}

{{ members | length }}
```

Number of members returned is zero.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm... this looks right to me, but you could try passing your `relatedTo` parameters as an array, Sean.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try passing your `relatedTo` parameters as an array:

```
{% set members = craft.users.group('members').relatedTo([ 'and', { targetElement: services }, { targetElement: locations } ]) %}
```

or a little easier to read:

```
{% set entries = craft.users({
    group: 'members',
    relatedTo: [
        'and',
        { targetElement: services },
        { targetElement: locations }
    ]
}) %}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to get only those users that are related to both services, add another relation to your parameter array:

```
{% set service1 = craft.categories.group('services').slug('service-1') %}
{% set service2 = craft.categories.group('services').slug('service-2') %}
{% set locations = craft.categories.group('locations').slug('location-1') %}

{% set entries = craft.users({
    group: 'members',
    relatedTo: [
        'and',
        { targetElement: service1 },
        { targetElement: service2 },
        { targetElement: locations }
    ]
}) %}
```

**Update:**
*(Copied the solution from Sean's [other question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5105/searching-members-fields), because it also fits here!)*

If you need to add those relations programatically, that's how I would do it:

```
{# Compose the relation param #}
{% set relationParam = ['and'] %}

{# Add to the relation param #}
{% if condition1 %}
    {% set service1 = craft.categories.group('services').slug('service-1') %}
    {% set relationParam = relationParam|merge([{ targetElement: service1 }]) %}
{% endif %}

{% if condition2 %}
    {% set service2 = craft.categories.group('services').slug('service-2') %}
    {% set relationParam = relationParam|merge([{ targetElement: service2 }]) %}
{% endif %}

{# Get users of group "member" #}
{% set users = craft.users.group('members') %}

{# Further filter users - avoid passing an array with `['and']` only #}
{% if relationParam|length > 1 %}
    {% set users = users.relatedTo(relationParam) %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This returns all members with either categories. It is possible to do something like: {% set services = craft.categories.group('services').slug('service-1 AND service-2') %} ?

Comment: Yes, will update my answer. Glad that passing the params as an array works!

Comment: Okay, I can see how this will work but there is an extra step I'll need help with...Another question...

Comment: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5105/searching-members-fields

Comment: Are you able to help with the linked question also?

Comment: @carlcs I think I may have spotted an error in that last block. I believe `relationParam|merge({ targetElement: service1 })` should be wrapped in brackets like so `relationParam|merge([{ targetElement: service1 }])`. I noticed it when adapting this for someone else's question.